# Getting date in format 20 Mar 2018 (Tue)

Tags: reporting-services

How can I display date as  dd MMM yyyy (ddd) in SSRS?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @nicky, I hope that you will take the time to review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the textbox and select <kbd>Text Box Properties...</kbd>

[image: right-click]

Then select <kbd>Number</kbd> and <kbd>Custom</kbd>.  After that, enter the date format.

[image]